# Error installing rmagick gem in RAILS 3.2.13

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, rmagick

any ideas why I'm getting this error:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/xiruki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
extconf.rb:128: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
checking for /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagickCore... no
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagick... no
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagick++... no
Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find the ImageMagick library or one of the dependent libraries. Check the mkmf.log file for more detailed information.

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/xiruki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby
    --with-MagickCorelib
    --without-MagickCorelib
    --with-Magicklib
    --without-Magicklib
    --with-Magick++lib
    --without-Magick++lib


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/xiruki/.bundler/tmp/635/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/xiruki/.bundler/tmp/635/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.13.1), and
Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.13.1'` succeeds
before bundling.
```

Tried a lot of workarounds but didn't work.

Tried to make `brew doctor` and `brew update` successful but no luck.

I had also successfully installed imagemagick using `brew install imagemagick`

I've also tried to uninstall and install again imagemagick by doing the ff:

```
brew uninstall imagemagick
brew install --fresh imagemagick
```

But seems like everything is not still working upon doing the `bundle install` or `bundle update rmagick` for my app.

I've tried doing `sudo gem install rmagick` and the weird thing is that it was successfully installed.

But can't bundle my app because it's stopping from the error above.

My app is trying to install `rmagick-2.13.1`

Upon viewing the version installed in my local, the version installed is `2.13.2`

Think i badly need to install the required version for the app.

I'm using MAC btw.

Comment: I'm getting this same error right now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I've just figured this out as I was struggling with the same issue:

Get back to a fresh imagemagick

Do this:

```
cd /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.6-3/lib
ln -s libMagick++-6.Q16.dylib libMagick++.dylib
ln -s libMagickCore-6.Q16.dylib libMagickCore.dylib
ln -s libMagickWand-6.Q16.dylib libMagickWand.dylib
```

You may or may not need to `brew install libtool`

then do this:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/libtool/2.4.2/lib/libltdl.7.dylib /usr/local/lib/libltdl.7.dylib
```

Then `gem install rmagick -v '2.13.1'`

And that should work, so then `bundle`

Good luck!